# Why i'm getting Unauthorized when trying to send PUT request from angular5 to spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-boot, angular5

I'm trying to send a PUT request from angular5 to to spring API , but i'm getting an error .

This is angular intervention.service.ts :

```
updateIntervention(id:number){
        if(this.authService.getToken()==null) {
          this.authService.loadToken();
        }
        return this.http.put(this.host+"/updateIntervention/"+id,
       {headers:new 
       HttpHeaders({'Authorization':this.authService.getToken()})});
      }

  Intervention.component.ts 

    valider(ref: Intervention){
        this.intervService.updateIntervention(ref.id)
          .subscribe((data:any)=>{
            console.log('there is no error ! ');
          },err=>{
            console.log('there is an error ! ');
          })

        ref.valid = !ref.valid;

       }
```

In Spring-boot :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateIntervention/{id}",method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public Intervention update(@PathVariable Long id){

        System.out.println("in intevention update");
        Intervention I = new Intervention();
        I = interventionRepo.getOne(id);
        I.setValid(true); // it's boolean , this is the goal from this update
        interventionRepo.save(I);

        return I  
    }
```

As error i get in angular :

```
{"timestamp":1527443447949,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized"}
```

As error In spring-boot :

```
access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
```

PS : this works when i send in angular both id and the object Ref , in spring , i write

```
 public Intervention update(@PathVariable Long id , @RequestBody Intervention I){ ... }
```

But i don't need this as all what i want is to modify the attribut valid in the entity Intervention .

**I'm using httpClient .**

Any idea ?

Comment: does the getToken method return the token or 'Bearer ' + token ?

Comment: Thanks for answering first , It returns Bearer + token, but as i said there is no problem with tokens , when i send both id and the object ref , everything goes well , but this is not what i want , i want to send only the id .isn't it possible to send only one parameter with Put request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The put method you are using has the following definition:

```
put(url: string, body: any | null, options)
```

You are providing the options object as a body parameter.And that's why you are getting unauthorized 401 which stands for "unauthenticated". Means that you have wrong or missing credentials.

You should change

```
return this.http.put(this.host+"/updateIntervention/"+id,
   {headers:new 
   HttpHeaders({'Authorization':this.authService.getToken()})});
  }
```

To:

```
return this.http.put(this.host+"/updateIntervention/"+id,
       null,
       {headers:new 
       HttpHeaders({'Authorization':this.authService.getToken()})});
      }
```

Comment: That was so much helpful , Thank you Man !